# Convert a decimal number with 10^6 digits to its binary representation

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, time-complexity, biginteger

Is it possible to convert a very large decimal number (containing **d** digits) to binary representation in **O(d)** time ?

here d = log(n), where d is no of digits in the decimal number ie: for eg 10^6. So that the number is obviously less than 10^(10^6).

If there is an algorithm that takes **O(d)** or **O(d<sup>c</sup>)** steps. Please share. where `d` is the number of digits in the decimal number.

Comment: If I read correctly, answer is no, you cannot convert a decimal number to binary representation in O(log n) where n is number of digits. As every digit needs to be scanned time complexity is at least O(n). If I didn't read correctly you should fix your question.

Comment: The language should have little to do with the time scaling to the number of digits.

Comment: I am trying to find a binary representation for a number with 10^6 digits. Can anyone suggest an optimal way to do so?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you misunderstood my question. here the number is less than 10^(10^6). and hence the no of digits is log(n)

Comment: Standard algorithm is `result = result * 10 + digit` which is O(log(n) ^ 2), in your notation, or `O(db)` where `d` is the number of decimal digits and `b` is the number of bits/bytes/uint64_t in the binary number.

Comment: This really depends on what you consider a "step" to be.  The best time-complexity to coding effort ratio you'll achieve will be using something like [Newton-Raphson division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division).  Or have a look at the string-to-binary implementations in one of many open source arbitrary-precision libraries.

Comment: So the question is: "can a decimal number `n` be converted to a binary number in `O(log n)` steps"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: how is the decimal number represented?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What are you using this number for in the first place?

Comment: There is no described algorithm, AFAIK. But you can use a divide and conquer algorithm, which, for sufficiently large values is indeed asymptotically faster than the simple algorithm, probably O(log N). I have already implemented the opposite (binary to decimal) and decimal to binary can be done similarly. But I have no code for it yet, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at [Brent and Zimmerman](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4710v1.pdf). AFAIK, they describe a recursive divide and conquer algorithm for this which is O(log N).

Comment: @WillihamTotland . I am using it for time complexity analysis. Liking finding the nth number in a sequence. Thus optimizing my algo to log(n) time so that its faster. (using mathematics). Also checking if binary conversion is good approach take or not. Leave the original problem to me.Please

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes. The decimal number should be sufficiently large too.

Comment: Correction: it is. of course, possible in O(n log n), not in O(log n). Multiple brain fart, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one for **O(d)**.

Proof (not strict):

A decimal number can be written as the sum over `k` of `x(k)*10^k`, where `x(k)` is the `k`th digit (starting with the least significant digit).

10 consists of the two factors 2 and 5. 2 is a simple bit shift, but 5 has of 2 bits set. This results of this is that the number of bits that must be adressed when adding digit `k` is not limited by any constant. For any konstant `m`, there is a `k` such that the number of non-zero bits in `1*10^k` is larger than `m`.

Thus, the (maximum) amount of work required per digit will not be constant, it will rise as `k` rises.